# MFC: How do I change background color in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

By default the color is gray, I want to change it.I use `OnEraseBkgnd` in my `MainFarm.h`,this works, it changes color,but when somewhere further in the code mfc changes it to gray again.

```
BOOL CMainFrame::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    CBrush backBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
    CBrush* pPrevBrush = pDC->SelectObject(&backBrush);
    CRect rect;
    pDC->GetClipBox(&rect);
    pDC->PatBlt(rect.left, rect.top, rect.Width(), rect.Height(),
        PATCOPY);
    pDC->SelectObject(backBrush);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Is this MDI application?

Comment: Yes,this is MDI application.

Comment: Add your brush as a member variable of the class and create it once. You are creating it in the handler so when it goes out of scope it is invalid.

Comment: Also, consider using the stock objects - I am sure there is a stock black brush. Stock objects do not need to be created.

Comment: it doesn't work, I change it, but somewhere further on in the code it turns gray again.

Comment: `pDC->SelectObject(backBrush);` - This leaves `backBrush` selected into a device context just two lines before the brush gets destroyed. Should probably be `pDC->SelectObject(pPrevBrush);`. This is unrelated to your immediate issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A MDI application doesn't just have frame windows and child windows. It also has a client window. The client window handles most of managing child windows.

But it also draws the client area of the frame window. This is what's drawing the grey background after you draw your background when you handle `OnEraseBkgnd` in the frame window.

Assuming your frame is derived from `CMDIFrameWndEx`, you should have a `OnEraseMDIClientBackground` virtual function that you can override to do the drawing you want.

If you're modifying older code, it's possible it uses an old enough version of MFC that's not present. If so, you need to create a window class and do the correct drawing in its `onEraseBkgnd`, create an instance of that in your frame window class, and in the frame window's `onCreate`, you subclass the MDI child window:

```cpp
class MyBkgndErase : public CWnd {
public:
    BOOL OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC) { 
        // drawing code here
    }
};

class MyFrameWnd : public CMDIFrameWnd {
    MyBkgndErase eraser;

    int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct) {

        // there's probably existing code you'll want to preserve here

        eraser.SubclassWindow(m_hWndMDIClient);
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Or, if you can switch to a newer version of MFC, you can *probably* just change your frame window's parent class from `CMDIFrameWnd` to `CMDIFrameWndEx`, and use `OnEraseMDIClientBackground` (which is undoubtedly easier).